# Logout using adal4j

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

How should i implement logout using adal4j ? Currently i dont see any methods in this library for doing this. Here is my example.

```
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + "test.onmicrosoft.com" + "/", true, service);

        try {
            final Future<AuthenticationResult> resultFuture = context.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    code, new URI(redirectUri), new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), "https://graph.windows.net/", null);

            result = resultFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

        }
```

Comment: Looks like no one has done this so far. I will be trying this using HttpClient...I will update once i make it work. Meanwhile if someone can tell me any other way of doing then I will be nice to try.